# How run time code modification is restricted by any OS?

Tags: c

To check whether I can change code at run time or not, I wrote a small piece of code(below) in linux.

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
        printf("reached inside the function");
        return a+b;
}

int main()
{
        int x=10;
        int y = 20;
        int * p;
        int z;
        int (*fp) (int , int);
        fp = add;
        p = (int *)fp;

        *(p+0) = 0;
        z = add(x,y);
}
```

As there is no issue from c coding point of view, compiler compiles is perfectly and link also happens. But at run time it fails with below error:

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Above error is perfect, because code segment is not supposed to be changed at run time, But I want to know how it is controlled at run time.

To know more about the code area restrictions, I ran readelf on the output file and result shows below in section headers:

```
[13] .text             PROGBITS        08048330 000330 0001cc 00  AX  0   0 16
```

where section header flag shows as "AX" , means this section is just allocatable and executable. It does not support writing ("W").

and with a small change in the elf file I was able to modify the flag of this section as "WAX" , as below:

```
[13] .text             PROGBITS        08048330 000330 0001cc 00 WAX  0   0 16
```

But still I get the same "segmentation fault" error.

I want to know - how is it achieved by the system?

Comment: See `mprotect()` for *nix-based systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system is ignoring the `W` flag here:

```
$ gcc -Wall file.c 
$ readelf -S a.out | grep .text
  [14] .text             PROGBITS        08048330 000330 0001cc 00  AX  0   0 16
$ objcopy a.out --set-section-flags .text=alloc,code,data a.out 
$ readelf -S a.out | grep .text
  [14] .text             PROGBITS        08048330 000330 0001cc 00 WAX  0   0 16
$ gdb -q a.out 
Reading symbols from a.out...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: a.out 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0804842f in main ()
(gdb) x/i 0x0804842f
0x804842f <main+45>:    movl   $0x0,(%eax)
(gdb)
```

You still  cannot write to `p`. You can change the memory page protection at runtime using [`mprotect`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int add(int a, int b)
{
        printf("reached inside the function");
        return a+b;
}

int main()
{
        int x=10;
        int y = 20;
        int * p;
        int z;
        int (*fp) (int , int);
        long pagesize;

        fp = add;
        p = (int *)fp;

        pagesize = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
        if(mprotect((void *)((uintptr_t)p & ~((uintptr_t)pagesize - 1)), pagesize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC) == -1)
          perror("Error mprotect()");

        *(p+0) = 0;
        z = add(x,y);
        return 0;
}
```

this will leave you with the bad instruction to fix:

```
$ gcc -Wall file.c 
$ ./a.out 
Segmentation fault
$ gdb -q a.out 
Reading symbols from a.out...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: a.out 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048484 in add ()
(gdb) x/i 0x08048484
0x8048484 <add>:    add    %al,(%eax)
(gdb)
```

Comment: Thank for your answer BSH, But I want to know more details on how system throws SIGESGV when a protected area is modified. What is the mechanism used internally to do it. Is there any role of MMU in this?

Comment: @Techie In x86, one of the checks the processor preforms before writing to some memory is to check if the page trying to write to is writable. If not, it raises page fault and calls the exception handler defined by the system, and the system takes it from there, for example calls the process `SIGSEGV` handler and terminate it. You can see [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Volume 3 System Programming Guide](http://goo.gl/b4l5We), Chapter 4: Paging, for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Does the segmentation fault happen at the same place?
It could be that the OS ignores the `W` flag, but I don't think that's the case here. Assuming the OS honours the flag, the following is relevant.

You are overwriting the first instruction of the `add` function with `0`, which in x86 assembly is (assuming 4 bytes `int` here)

```
00000000  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000002  0000              add [bx+si],al
```

This most likely ends up accessing invalid memory, at `bx+si`.